# Google Drive web view link retrieved in Google API explorer, but not in my code

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have code that uploads files to Google Drive and sets the appropriate permissions so that anyone in the domain can read them.

If I use the [Google Drive API explorer](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get) and enter the Id of the file and enter "webViewLink" in the "fields" textbox, then when I execute the request, I see something like this (actual link obfuscated)...

```json
{
 "webViewLink": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/abcdef123456/view?usp=drivesdk"
}
```

Entering the link in a private browser window allows me to see the file as expected.

However, if I try to get the link in my C# code...

```cs
FilesResource.GetRequest request = _service.Files.Get(fileId);
request.Fields = "webViewLink";
var file = await _service.Files.Get(fileId).ExecuteAsync();
```

...then the `file.WebViewLink` property is always blank. Looking at the network tab, it seems is if the same API is being called with the same parameters,

Anyone any ideas? I have double-checked, and I'm using the same Google account in both the API explorer and my code (I know this because otherwise I wouldn't be able to see other files in the drive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C# code sets up a request and sets the `Fields` on it but then you call the `_service.Files.Get(fileId)` again so you're ignoring the original request you set up with the additional `Fields`, therefore it is using the default `Fields` and not the ones you set up.

Try doing `var file = await request.Get(fileId).ExecuteAsync();` so it'll use the `Fields` set up for that requset.

Comment: Ho hum, I think it's past my bedtime! Thanks